# Rails 5: Find or create with .each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm making a `GET` request to Typeform. If the request is successful, I'm saving the response as `order` to the database. My problem lays in this particular part:

`current_user.find_or_create_by(landing_id: item["landing_id]) do |order|`

If a user submits a new Typeform the method won't find a `landing_id` and therefore will create all `orders` again. But those `orders` already exist in the database therefore each `order` is saved multiple times into my database.

How can I avoid this?

```
items = response.parsed_response["items"]
 items.each do |item|
  @order = current_user.orders.find_or_create_by(landing_id: item["landing_id"]) do |order|
   order.landing_id = item["landing_id"]
   order.email = item["hidden"]["email"]
   order.price = item["hidden"]["price"]
   order.project = item["hidden"]["project"]
   order.save!
  end
 end
```

Comment: `won't find a landing_id and therefore will create all orders again. But those orders already exist in the database` You say it won't find a `landing_id` and you say the orders exist but you are looking by a `landing_id`, if the orders exists then you should look by the field that does exist.

Comment: Probably I stated the question wrong. I'll try it to make it more clearer. There are 2 orders in my database one has landing_id XXX and the oher has YYY. Now the user decides to submit a new form. Therefore I'm making a GET request to the Typeform, but this Typeform Response has the landing_id ZZZ. Until now there is no order with landing_id ZZZ in my database. So it will create a new record. The problem now is that it also creates a duplicate record of landing_id XXX and YYY. Sorry for grammar I'm one the phone.

Comment: I'd suggest you to add the `byebug` gem and debug your code. I don't understand why would it create more than one order but I don't now what's on `items` either. Debug the request step by step and I guess you'll find what's creating the extra orders.

Answer (score 1):

Active Record documentation for [**find_or_create_by**](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) :

> Please note *this method is not atomic*, it runs first a SELECT, and if there are no results an INSERT is attempted. If there are other threads or processes there is a race condition between both calls and it could be the case that you end up with two similar records.

Anyway you can get around this problem by adding a uniq constraint to the combination of `user_id` and `landing_id` columns:

```
add_index :orders, [:user_id, :landing_id], unique: true
```

And change your code accordingly:

```
items = response.parsed_response["items"]
items.each do |item|
  begin
    Order.transaction(requires_new: true) do
      @order = current_user.orders.find_or_create_by(landing_id: item["landing_id"]) do |order|
        order.landing_id = item["landing_id"]
        order.email = item["hidden"]["email"]
        order.price = item["hidden"]["price"]
        order.project = item["hidden"]["project"]
        order.save!
      end
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
    next
  end
end
```